# Apache server setting on ubuntu

Tags: apache2

Can any one help me setting a Apache2 server on Ubuntu. MY current Apache2 site-enabled configuration file can be seen on http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/852570http://paste.ubuntu.com/852602/ ... My requirement is when I type my ip in browserlike 192.168.0.10:8080/linaro, iT should disply the content of my linro DIRECTORY.

Comment: Sry The url is some waht messed up .. The correct uel is http://paste.ubuntu.com/852602/